# I have got a problem in running the hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar file

Tags: hadoop

After downloadding the jar file I clicked and the message comes as blocked(The file '/home/hadoop/Downloads/hadoop-core-1.2.jar' is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dange

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382459/foo-jar-is-not-marked-as-executable) help?

Comment: The more important question is probably: what are you hoping to achieve by double-clicking on this jar?

Answer (score 0):

That file is a client library. There is nothing that "clicking" it would run.

However, as the warning says, there *could* be executable JAR files named anything that *are harmful*.

---

If you are trying to actually run a Hadoop cluster, then download the full package from the Apache site (preferrably Hadoop 3.x), rather than one of many JAR files from version 1.2.